# Popup problem...Not sure if this is the best way to do this

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I have written a script that allows a customer to log in, and download their contract in PDF.

We want the contract PDF to open in a popup, but are experiencing problems with customers who don't understand the basics of web browsers...

Basically, the customer logs in and a link is generated for their contract.  The link is bound through jQuery's live event handler, that takes the request, sends it to an AJAX logging function then opens the PDF via window.open.

Since it is a user's action that opens the window, I can only think that because it goes through 2 other functions first, it is making the pop-up blocker kick in.

Does anybody have any better ideas?

My code is all over the place, in differnt namespaces, so I hope you guys can figure it all out:

Generate the link in a call back function, if the customer's credentials are correct:

```
$("#pdfLinks").prepend("<span><a href='#' id='pdfLink'><img src='img/btnDownloadPdf.png' alt='Downdload PDF' /><br>Download Adobe &copy; PDF<\/a><\/span>");
                                        $("#pdfLink").live('click', function() {
                                                UI.showWorkingDialog();
                                                net.tssol.contract.log(contractId['contract'], "DOWNLOAD_PDF", lead);
                                        });
                                        $("#pdfLinks").prepend("<h5>Adobe PDF<\/h5>");
```

the tssol.log function:

```
log: function(contract, method, lead) {
        $.post("log.php", { lead: lead,
                            method: method}, 
                            function(log) {
            if (log['success'] == true) {
                if (method == "DOWNLOAD_PDF") {
                    // change to window.open for popup
                    window.open("http://oururl.net/public_html/viewPdf.php?verify=" + contract, '', 'scrollbars=1,menubar=0,height=600,width=800,resizable=1,toolbar=0,location=0,status=0');
```

Let me know if you guys see any way to make the user experience better.

Thanks

Comment: Popups get blocked. That's hardly the fault of the user. You're programmatically generating a new window using Javascript, that's not a result of a direct action on their part. Could you try setting the target property of the link to _blank in the HTML itself and use Javascript to rewrite the HREF? That way the user's action WILL be opening a new window, the difference is that you dicatate the location.

Comment: Sorry, to clear that up.. Open a _blank window, log then redirect the opened window on success of the log function?

Comment: Something like that. The window will (hopefully) already be opened that way. Just a suggestion, which is why I haven't posted it as an answer :\

Comment: Cool, good idea.. I'll see what I can come up with. Thanks!

Comment: Another alternative is write a function that tests if a popup blocker is blocking it, if not create a link to another page that doesn't open in a new window...not quite as elegant and it sounds like alot of work...  When I log into my bank and cell phone websites, I don't have any problems with the bill PDF's opening in a popup...But that could also because I allowed it and don't remember...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can provide a HTML Version of the contract in a popup and add a "Download PDF" Button at the bottom of the popup content?

But in general you shouldnt use popups since they are often blocked by the web browsers and are in users head synced with trash and viagra-advertising.. you know what I mean ;)

I would do a jQuery Lightbox-like popup inside the website with the HTML-Contract, and optionally offer a PDF Download Button!
Have a look at this one: http://fancybox.net/

Comment: yea that looks really good...alot of reworking tho...but i'm hourly so who cares...  But like my comment above, I was following the presidence of my cell phone and bank....

Comment: @guyfromfl since when does anyone like bank interfaces?